# react-native command gives syntaxerror

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

Currently using `react-native-cli: 1.0.0` and `react-native: 0.26.3`

Running `react-native` command in terminal gives this error.

> /Users/appleuser/Desktop/asklegit-app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:229
>         throw err;
>         ^
>       SyntaxError: /Users/appleuser/package.json: Error while parsing JSON - Unexpected end of input
>       at Object.parse (native)
>       at OptionManager.addConfig (/Users/appleuser/Desktop/asklegit-app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:225:62)
>       at OptionManager.findConfigs (/Users/appleuser/Desktop/asklegit-app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:442:30)
>       at OptionManager.init (/Users/appleuser/Desktop/asklegit-app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:484:12)
>       at compile (/Users/appleuser/Desktop/asklegit-app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:112:69)
>       at loader (/Users/appleuser/Desktop/asklegit-app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:158:14)
>       at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/appleuser/Desktop/asklegit-app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:168:7)
>       at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:367:17)

Anyone got a clue? Couldn't find anything online :(

This is my *package.json*

```
{
  "name": "asklegit",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "android": "react-native run-android"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.26.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: post your package.json please

Comment: @KRONWALLED that is my app's package.json but why is the error coming from my global package.json

Comment: I think there is a empty package.json at `/Users/appleuser/package.json`. Could you look into it and if it is empty delete it?

Comment: @KRONWALLED Sweet! Thank you that worked!

Comment: @KRONWALLED nice catch , you should post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know under which circumstances but it seems sometimes there is an empty `package.json` created in the users home directory. A completely empty file is by default not correct syntax so calling applications will produce an error.

Solution is to just delete the empty `package.json`.